# Release:library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I have some strange error,I use cocoapods for my project.

when I Go to Product > Edit Scheme then Click on Build, my project run well.

But Click on Release,I got an error

> ''library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking''
>
> "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)."

This is my environment.

- Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5
- Xcode 6.4
- iOS SDK 8.4

I know how to work with cocoapods. I used this pods in a few projects, but this problem I see at first time.this is my pods

> platform:ios,'7.0'
>
> pod "AFNetworking","~>2.5.2"
>
> pod "SDWebImage", "~> 3.7.2"
>
> pod "MJRefresh","~> 1.4.7"
>
> pod "MJExtension", "~> 2.1.1"
>
> pod "IQKeyboardManager","~>3.2.4"

I have tried

- pod install and clean the project
- try "Build Active Architecture Only" = YES
- reinstalled cocoapods
- clean DerivedData

But they are useless.

So someone who can help me,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

OK，I already know the answer.

Because the format has changed after the upgrade cocoapods.

In

> builldsetting -> other linker flags

change

> -lPods-AFNetworking into -l "AFNetworking"

others the same. You first remove all the libraries out to be re- pod install.

Comment: I have tried same but not working :( any other solution. please check screen shot of my project
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uosyeocauw77yby/Screen%20Shot%202017-10-24%20at%206.43.30%20PM.png?dl=0